# How find current input value for controller action?

Tags: .net-core

I'm try update multiple rows in my controller for each row in loop, but instead of this updated are every rows with value from first input.

This is Razor part:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.ce.Count; i++)
{
    var cur = ViewBag.ce[i];

    <input id="Text1" type="text" value="@cur.Price" name="Pric" />
    <input id="Text2" type ="hidden" value="@cur.ProductCode" name="id" />
}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
}
```

And here is controller part:

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(int? Pric, int? id)
 {
  var model =  db.Reward.Where(h => h.Category == 1).ToList();
  for (var i =0; i < model.Count; i++)
    {
    var curr = model[i];
    curr.Price =  Pric;
    }

 db.SaveChanges();
 return View();
 }
```

Values before:

```
 100
 200
 300
 400
```

Values after click button "Save":

```
 100
 100
 100
 100
```

What i need?:

```
   100 --> change to (Pric input value)
   200 --> change to (Pric input value)
   300 --> change to (Pric input value)
   400 --> change to (Pric input value)
```

Comment: Try: `var model =  db.Reward.Where(h => h.Category == 1 && h.Id == id.Value).ToList();`

Comment: The `name` of the input must be unique in the form. You have a cycle that creates the same input many times. You should create an `id` that has `i` inside, like `id="Text1_@i"` and array construct in the name `name="Pric[@i]"`on the action method side you should have two `int[]` parameters.

Comment: I get NULL with 
      name="Pric[@i]"